# c# exclude hyphen from directory.getdirectories

Tags: c#, file-io, directory, getdirectories

I would like to use the Directory.GetDirectories method to get all directories with some exclusions.  In particular I need to exclude directories that have a hyphen in them.  I already found out regular expressions to not work as search patterns.  What search pattern would I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a linq query would be sufficient?

```
    //query notation
    var result = from d in Directory.GetDirectories(path) 
                 where !d.Contains("-")
                 select d;
    //'dot' notation
    var result2 = Directory.GetDirectories(path)
                  .Where(dir => !dir.Contains("-"));
```

EDIT(More explanation)

The solution above is called ["LINQ to Objects"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx). It is a way of querying collections that implement `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` interface. The `GetDirectories` method returns `Array` of string that is eligible to use Linq. There is a lot of stuff about Linq on the internet. To see te power of Linq flick through these examples on MSDN: [101 Linq Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746). BTW Linq is useful to retrieve data from various sources like XML, databases etx.

Comment: I am a new computer science student.  I do not recognize a lot of that code.  Can you reference some material to help me understand it?

Comment: If using .NET 4.0, I'd strongly recommend using [`Directory.EnumerateDirectories()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383304.aspx) instead.

Comment: @Paul I have enclosed more information which might be useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<string> resultDirs=new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<string> ();
            foreach (string  dir in System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories("path"))
            {
                if (!dir.Contains("-")) resultDirs.Add(dir);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not LINQ way:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string StartingPath = "c:\\";

        List<string> mydirs = new List<string>(); // will contains folders not containing "-"

        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(StartingPath))
        {                               
            if (!(d.Contains("_")))
            {
                mydirs.Add(d);
            }                

            foreach (string dir in mydirs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dir);
            }
        }
    }
}
```